# No Longer Able to Create Live USB

Tags: boot, 14.04, live-usb, unetbootin, startup-disk-creator

I've tried all of the suggestions I could find from forums and Q&A sites (like this one), but I am still not able to live boot Ubuntu 14.04 from USB.

I am using a SanDisk Cruzer 32GB.

I have tried:

1. Reformatting as FAT32
2. Wiping and rebuilding the MBR
3. Using several different tools including unetbootin and the built-in live USB creator
4. Checking boot flags
5. Recreating the partition table

Yes, my BIOS recognizes the drive. Yes, this drive *can* be booted from.

I have made a bootable USB drive at least 20 times in the past with the same drive without a problem. Any Ideas?

Comment: Please describe the problem. The application (live creator /unmetbootin) fails, or you can not boot ? What error message and what behavior ? Have you checked the md5 sum of the iso ?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen There are no errors until I try to boot at which point it says something like: "Boot failure, press any key to continue."

Comment: Have you checked the disk image with `md5sum`? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out my issue, hopefully it will help you, Andrew.  In looking at the Partitioning options for the USB key, I see that there was an MBR and a GPT option.  You have to ensure you are partitioning with MBR.  GPT appears not to create a partition recognized by UEFI or legacy BIOS.  I repartitioned, ensuring MBR was selected, reformated FAT32, and now have two USB keys that work, the Corsair Voyager 16GB and the SanDisk Cruizer Glide 32GB.